# Is there a way to show the "Bibliography" in Greek in Bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

I want to make a bibliography section in bibtex and I have this problem: I need the title "Bibliogrphy" to be in greek but the contents of my bibliograpy in english. I use the command \selectlanguage{english} because I write in greek and I get this result.[image]

Without using using the previous command I get this result [image]

All I want is a combination of these two photos. The title to be in greek and the rest in english, if it is possible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you use.

Comment: Please post actual code here and not images of code. See for example [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) on how to create a MWE.

Comment: It should be easier with `babel` and `biblatex`.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

Comment: sorry I am new to this... but I can send you what you need to know to help me

Comment: Are you free to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

With babel, you can redefine the Bibliography name for the english language like this:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{\selectlanguage{greek}Bibliograf\'ia}%
}
```

(to be placed in your preamble)

Then you can use `\selectlanguage{english}` just before the bibliography.